# FCM WebPush valid token throwing errorCode: "UNREGISTERED"

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

**Problem**

I retrieve a token through `messaging.getToken()` and send it a message via the http v1 API. I then receive the following error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "UNREGISTERED"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How is it possible that I return a valid token with `messaging.getToken()` and then receive the error message above when sending to it?

**Attempted Solution**

I have investigated `onTokenRefresh()` but this does not appear to be the problem (although I am finding that `onTokenRefresh()` is not easy to test). The token still exists and is still valid, however it throws the error above. I have had this problem for several months.

Comment: Hello! I'm having a similar problem. Have you figured out how to solve it?